# How to access nested coordinates of poly border from a json file and plot them on my leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, geojson

I am trying to have a user select a country from my dropdown list of countries and have that countries border drawn on the map.

I am struggling with how to access the coordinates from the countryBorders.geo.json file which holds all the info I need. It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Bahamas",
        "iso_a2": "BS",
        "iso_a3": "BHS",
        "iso_n3": "044"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -77.53466,
                23.75975
              ],
              [
                -77.78,
                23.71
              ],
              [
                -78.03405,
                24.28615
              ],
              [
                -78.40848,
                24.57564
              ],
              [
                -78.19087,
                25.2103
              ],
              [
                -77.89,
                25.17
              ],
              [
                -77.54,
                24.34
              ],
              [
                -77.53466,
                23.75975
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -77.82,
                26.58
              ],
              [
                -78.91,
                26.42
              ],
              [
                -78.98,
                26.79
              ],
              [
                -78.51,
                26.87
              ],
              [
                -77.85,
                26.84
              ],
              [
                -77.82,
                26.58
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                -77,
                26.59
              ],
              [
                -77.17255,
                25.87918
              ],
              [
                -77.35641,
                26.00735
              ],
              [
                -77.34,
                26.53
              ],
              [
                -77.78802,
                26.92516
              ],
              [
                -77.79,
                27.04
              ],
              [
                -77,
                26.59
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
```

This is the first country and the file holds all countries of the world.

My js file looks like this so far:

```html
const mymap = L.map('mainMap').setView([0, 0], 5);
const attribution =
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
tiles.addTo(mymap);



let marker = L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(mymap);

//populate dropdown menu
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/countryBorders.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.border.features.length; i++) {
                $('#countryInput').append($('<option>', {
                    value: result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a2,
                    text: result.data.border.features[i].properties.name,
                }));
            }
        }
    });


//run button to plot border on map
$('#btnRun').click(function () {
    let name = $('#countryInput').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/countryBorders.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',

        //code to get coordinates of selected country and plot on map

                })
    });
```

and my php looks like this

```html
<?php

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

    $result = file_get_contents('countryBorders.geo.json');

    $border = json_decode($result,true);
    $countryInfo = json_decode($result,true);

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";

    $output['data']['border'] = $border;
    $output['data']['countryInfo'] = $countryInfo;

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

All help much appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to loop over the `features`, until you find the one with the properties->name value that you're interested in. Or use array_filter instead of a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm kind of confused as to why it's a loop through features and not a loop through features.geometry.coordinates? i know i'm missing something somewhere along the line

Comment: `features` is an array. It contains only one object in what you have shown us, but likely there will be more. So you need to loop those features first, to find the one you are actually interested in. Only then can you loop over the geometry -> coordinates of that one.